# FIM Wrong accountType error

Tags: active-directory, identity-management

I have an Active directory containing an universal security group named GG_H_W4M2MD it has several members. I have a "normal" user account named 26626.

Both are managed using FIM 2010 R2 (Forefront Identity Manager). When I add the user to the group using active directory users and computer snapin everything works. When fim tries, it gets a connected datasource error. The error is:

> A new member could not be added to a local group because the member
>   has the wrong account type.

I have no clue as to what this pertains to. Anyone seen this error before in FIM? Management of other users (even in the same group) works fine. But I cannot find any differences.

P.S. Not using fim portal, we are talking fim sync service.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I have the same issue like you and I also cannot find any difference in any of the accounts that should be added.

Comment: No, never solved it.